# How can I extend Eclipse Java search to JSPs?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags

Friends,

Our JSP code uses both Spring form tags and JSTL tags. Is there a way that when I search for getFoo() in the Eclipse Java Search, for Eclipse to also return uses of the foo property in the JSP files?

I suspect the answer is "no", because there isn't a way at compile time to tell the types of the JSP beans, but its worth asking, right?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaEE distro of Eclipse will do that, but only in those cases where the JSP contains type information. Ironically, this only really happens with `<jsp:useBean>`, which is the old, pre-JSTL way of declaring java beans in the JSP. New-style JSPs are pretty devoid of java type info, and Eclipse has little or nothing to get a handle on.